# Doctrine 2 Gedmo extensions not working with error: "does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

We are having issues getting Gedmo plugins to work in our ZF 2 Doctrine 2 installation

We are getting this error from generate entities:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable" in property Wallet\Entity\Entity::$created does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

Our entity looks like this:

```
...
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
...

/**
* @var datetime $created
*
* @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
*/
public $created;
...
```

We have also tried:

```
/**
* @var datetime $created
*
* @\Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="create")
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
*/
public $created;
```

And

```
/**
* @var datetime $created
*
* @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable(on="create")
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
*/
public $created;
```

We have verified that the path is correct and that the php class exists at that path.

Our module config looks like this:

```
'doctrine' => array(
        'eventmanager' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'subscribers' => array(
                    'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener',
                    'Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener',
                    'Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener',
                    'Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener',
                    'Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Our composer config looks like this:

```
...
"require": {
...
            "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.4.*",
…
```

We have also tried:

```
...
"require": {
...
            "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.*",
…
```

None of the articles I have found on the issue have helped so far.

Any suggestions you can offer would be very appreciated.

All the best.

Will

Comment: An update here -- we have found the plugin works when we access the website via the zend framework stack, but it is failing during entities generation from doctrine console. Any advice very apperciated

Comment: The ZF2 Doctrine Module places a script at `vendor/bin/doctrine-module` which you should use for console access. ie, from your app route on the command line try `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:info`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Our developer fixed it over the weekend when we realized that we were missing loading in the listeners in the console.php. He added them like so: $evm = new \Doctrine\Common\EventManager();
$evm->addEventSubscriber(new \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener());

Answer (score 0):

Our developer fixed it over the weekend when we realized that we were missing loading in the listeners in the console.php.

He added them like so: $evm = new \Doctrine\Common\EventManager(); $evm->addEventSubscriber(new \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener());

He found his sample code here:

https://gist.github.com/l3pp4rd/964075